# Pandas Comprehension to Change Row value based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, index-error, for-comprehension

SOLVED by Bruno0. answer is below, with additional fixes in comments. I have left the description of the problem, but placed the corrected code in the code block for reference.
I have a frame `nfl_frame` I've scraped with NFL Player's fantasy Scores. The Table is sorted by:
-Week in ascending order
-Position in this order QB->RB->WR->TE->K->Defense
-Points in descending order
It looks like this, but with many more players and rows:
Week    Name    Fanduel_Points
1   Wilson, Russell 31.78   
1   Rodgers, Aaron  30.76   
1   Allen, Josh     28.18   
1   Jackson, Lamar  27.50   
1   Murray, Kyler   27.30   
1   Kamara, Alvin   31.00   
1   Elliot, Zeke    30.00
2   Philadelphia    1.00    
2   Jacksonville    0.00    
2   Cincinnati     -2.00    
2   Detroit        -3.00    
2   Dallas         -3.00

What I'd like to do is add a column with the player's position. Since the week and points sorting is consistent, I figured I could write a list comprehension that would check for if the points scored was higher than the previous row, and iterate along a list of positions to add the label when that occurred. Then, when the week for a row was higher than the previous row, we'd reset the index to start from QB again. the code looks like this:

```py
##writing comprehension to perform task listed above
#creating empty list that I will add each position to
Result = ['QB']
#list of positions
Positions = list(['QB','RB','WR','TE','Def'])
def add_position(df):
    #creating list of my positions
    #setting index as 0 to start with QB
    Role = 0
    #loop checking for week number and points scored
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        #if week for new row matches week for last row, and points for new row <= last row, then same position as last row
        if df.Week[i]== df.Week[i-1] and df.Fanduel_Points[i]<= df.Fanduel_Points[i-1]:
            Result.append(Positions[Role])
        #if week for new row matches week for last row, and points for new row > last row, then next position in list
        elif df.Week[i] == df.Week[i-1] and df.Fanduel_Points[i] > df.Fanduel_Points[i-1]:
            Role +=1
            Result.append(Positions[Role])
        #if new week, reset and begin from Positions[0] to begin labeling as QB again
        elif df.Week[i] > df.Week[i-1] :
            Role = 0
            Result.append(Positions[Role])
#running my comprehension on the frame
add_position(nfl_frame)
#apply add_position to my position column
nfl_frame['Position'] = Result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role is used as an index for List Position, but is unbounded.

Thus if in a given week you have more than 6 lines with always increasing Fanduel_Price, as expressed in this line

```
elif df.Week[i] == df.Week[i-1] and df.Fanduel_Price[i] > df.Fanduel_Price[i-1]:
```

Then Role with reach a value of 6 and you get this index out of range error.

You could limit the increasing of Role as follows

```
Role=min(Role+1, len(Positions)-1)
```

Comment: Thank you! This made me realize that I erroneously put "Price" instead of "Points" for my if/elifs. However, the position is being listed as QB every time instead of continuing as expected. Any chance you can figure out why my row number isn't increasing?

Comment: well, it seems that the line Role +=1 is never executed, thus the condition above is always false. This is strange for row "1 Kamara, Alvin 31.00" where I would expect it to be true. Are you sure about the content of each column of the df dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for looking! Just just checked and confirmed it is sorted in that order. Here is a full copy of the content if it would help: https://github.com/CSorrel58/FanduelResearch/blob/master/nfl_weekly_fanduel_scores.csv

Comment: I checked the content of the file and it looks ok. Thus now I suppose the problem is that your function returns a single string while you expect a new column of the dataframe.

Comment: I checked the content of the file and it looks ok. Thus now I suppose the problem is that your function returns a single string while you expect a new column of the dataframe. Initialize a list before the loop like ````Result = ['NA']```` then instead of returning values, append the value in the list ```Result.append(Positions[Role])``` and finally add the new column to the dataframe ```df['Positions'] = ```Result```.

Comment: That worked great Bruno! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I would recommend to factor ```Result.append(Positions[Role])``` out of the if...elif.... This would separate responsibilitities (update Role / update Result) and open the door to further refactoring.